# judging the intended meaning of the two sentences below

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives, adverbs

> James is Max's **supposedly** Irish ancestor.
>
> james is Max's **supposed** Irish ancestor.

What can we interpret from these? Which is the correct one?

I understand that "supposedly" modifies the adjective "Irish" and "supposed" modifies "ancestor". But it doesn't help me reach a conclusion about the uncertainty factor of the sentence.

Is there uncertainty about James being Irish or max's ancestor?

No context, just the two independent sentences.

Comment: In sentence #1, Max has an ancestor. this ancestor may be James, and James may be Irish. In sentence #2, however, James is Irish and may be Max's Irish ancestor (while it cannot be clearly inferred that Max necessarily has an Irish ancestor).

Comment: I can't really say OP's distinction strikes a chord with me. My immediate thought is that "supposed" here is a slightly unusual usage, so following standard procedure I'd look for a possible semantic distinction. Since *supposedly* is normally a somewhat dismissive way of showing skepticism (the ancestor isn't *really* Irish, even though he claims to be), I just imagine *supposed* as having some vague sense of *whatever James may be, he's probably **not** Max's Irish ancestor, despite people thinking that he is*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - *James is Max's supposedly Irish ancestor*.
> - *James is Max's supposed Irish ancestor*.

In the first sentence, *supposedly* modifies *Irish*. The sentence implies that James is Max's ancestor and that he is supposedly Irish.

In the second one, the adjective *supposed* modifies the noun *ancestor*. And so, the sentence implies that James may or may not be Max's ancestor, but James is certainly Irish.

As long as you cannot offer any context to determine whether James is actually Irish, or whether he may or may not be Max's ancestor, I'd say that both sentences are acceptable, and grammatically correct regardless of any contexts.